# Where to put the sub dataset in a windows loop when running gdal translate on NetCDFdata?

Tags: netcdf, gdal-translate, osgeo4w, windows-10

I need to run below command and it works great (note the -sds).

```
for %A in ("C:\temp\*.nc") do gdal_translate -a_nodata 65535 -stats -ot Float32 -unscale -a_srs "+init=epsg:4326" -sds -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 "%A" "%A.tiff
```

but my NetCDF has 3 subdatasets and I only need it to run on one of them.
so I used (note the :sst in the next to last argument)

```
for %A in ("C:\temp\*.nc") do gdal_translate -a_nodata 65535 -stats -ot Float32 -unscale -a_srs "+init=epsg:4326"  -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 "%A:sst" "%A.tiff
```

The error is

> ERROR 4: `C:\temp\a.nc:sst' does not exist in the file system,

but it does not recognize the sub dataset Here is what GDALINFO returns

> SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF5:"a.nc"://sst   SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[4320x8640]
>   //sst (16-bit unsigned integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the SDS Name *exactly* as reported by `gdalinfo`, i.e the HDF5 prefix is required.

i.e. `HDF5:"a.nc"://sst` or `HDF5:"C:\Temp\a.nc"://sst`

Try something like: (you may need to fiddle with quoting, I haven't tested)

```
for %A in ("C:\temp\*.nc") do gdal_translate -a_nodata 65535 -stats -ot Float32 -unscale -a_srs "+init=epsg:4326"  -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 HDF5:"%A"://sst %A.tiff
```

Comment: thanks again Luke, I tried most combinations of that but not both the HDF5: and ://sst together. I was hung up on just using sst and not //sst although I did try that but on an attempt without HDF5.